# how to avoid direct to another anchor when scroll mobile device screen and touch it to make it stop?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem when developing hybird mobile app. I want to know how to avoid redirect to another anchor when scroll  mobile device screen and touch it to make it stop?

For example ,I have a page which has so many  tags and has a very big height attribute,so the page would scroll .But when the page was scrolling ,when I just want to stop scroll the page and watch some detail content,I touch the screen .But unexpectedly triggered the  tag anchor ,so redirect to another anchor.I don't want the bad user experience,I want to delay more time so when I touch the screen the scroll would stop and  after maybe 500ms  ,I click a  tag I can get another anchor.

I also have a simple jsfidle for that to make the question more understandable .

https://jsfiddle.net/6h57hwwf/

some core code for that

```
<body>
<div>
<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.bing.com">www.facebook.com</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.bing.com">www.facebook.com</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="http://www.bing.com">www.facebook.com</a>
</div>
<div>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Did you test this on a mobile device? And is the screen auto-scrolling until you touch it or do you have to manually scroll it?

Comment: yes, I have test it on my mobile phone and indeed the problem exists.when I scroll  quickly by my hand ,the page content would continue scroll for about 3 seconds. when I touch the screen again,the screen content would stop scroll but if there is a a  tag ,there usually redirected to another location.

Comment: What phone are you using? I tested your fiddle on an iPhone 6 and I always notice that when I scroll in a browser, I can touch the screen to stop scrolling. But if I really would like to press an URL or tag, I have to press the screen again.

Comment: Probably it's your browser issue, just tested your fiddle in Android Chrome and the scrolling just stops.

Comment: I think jsfiddle is not very good for test the problem .  I have updated the html file to my blog .
http://hktkdy.com/demo/

Comment: source code:https://github.com/zhangolve/zhangolve.github.io/tree/master/demo

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution regardless of the underlying browser: add a transparent element that covers the whole container when scrolling, rendering none of the anchors clickable, and hide it in 500ms after the scrolling stops.

```
const mask = document.getElementById('mask');
mask.style.visibility = 'hidden';

const showMask = () => {
 if (mask.style.visibility === 'hidden')
   mask.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

const hideMask = () => {
  if (mask.style.visibility === 'visible')
   mask.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
const debounced = _.debounce(hideMask, 1000);
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
 showMask();
 debounced();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8bz7dd7p/1/

Note that I add a color in the mask for illustration, also, the function to hide the mask should be debounced.