# removeEventListener doesn't seems to work?

Tags: javascript, dom

for some reason ,I need to delay click and preventDefault for some time when scroll page end.So I write something like this :

```
// const disableClickDuringScrollHandler=(e)=> {
//      e.preventDefault();
//    };
this.scrollHandler = e => {
  console.log('scrolling');
  const disableClickDuringScrollHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  document.addEventListener('click', disableClickDuringScrollHandler);
  window.clearTimeout(this.scrollTimer);
  this.scrollTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('scroll end');
    document.removeEventListener('click', disableClickDuringScrollHandler);
  }, 300);
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler);
```

I also has been write a codepen: https://codepen.io/zhangolve/pen/gRNMoX

my question is when I put disableClickDuringScrollHandler outside of the scrollHandler ,removeEventListener can work well,but when I put disableClickDuringScrollHandler inside of the scrollHandler ,removeEventListener doesn't seem to work .

I have tried so many times to found why but failed.So I get here to ask your help.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to prevent clicking during scroll. What issue are you trying to solve with this ?

Comment: In mobile site ,when scrolling the page , if someone touches the screen to let scroll ends,sometimes that will trigger a click and redirect to another href location .for avoiding the issue ,I write some code like this  .@Rajesh P
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095681/how-to-avoid-direct-to-another-anchor-when-scroll-mobile-device-screen-and-touch

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each time the user scrolls, you create a new `disableClicksDuringScroll` closure and add it as a click listener. When this timer runs, it removes the latest click listener, but not the previous ones (because they're different closures, so they aren't equal to the function you're removing this time).

You should define `disableClicksDuringScroll` function just once, outside the `scroll` handler, since it doesn't refer to any local variables here. Then when you call `removeEventListener` it will find this handler.

You can also use a variable so you only add the click listener once, when scrolling starts, not every time you reset the timer.

```js
this.disableClickDuringScrollHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
};

this.inScroll = false;

this.scrollHandler = e => {
  console.log('scrolling');
  if (!this.inScroll) {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.disableClickDuringScrollHandler);
    this.inScroll = true;
  }
  window.clearTimeout(this.scrollTimer);
  this.scrollTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.inScroll = false;
    console.log('scroll end');
    document.removeEventListener('click', disableClickDuringScrollHandler);
  }, 300);
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler);
```